# Duplicate tags [application] [patent-applications]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[application](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application) and [patent-applications](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patent-applications) are duplicates. I prefer the latter.

Answer (score 0):

https://patents.stackexchange.com/tags/patent-applications/synonyms

Added the synonym, now it needs votes.

> Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.